# MAGMI says it imported, but didn't (works locally though)?

Tags: magento, magmi

I downloaded the latest MAGMI (version 0.7.21) and set it up to import one configurable product **locally on xampp**. After some time it worked, the product was imported including images.

So I uploaded the local MAGMI folder to the root of my Magento on the server, changed the database connection settings and imported again. I got the same screen as I got locally, but no items were imported. I imported again with all import options MAGMI offers, it just wont import any items and **no new items can be found in the item grid in Magento admin**.

So I started searching for that problem on Google and found that sometimes MAGMI messes up the enabled/disabled state. That was not the problem in my case.

I am running Magento 1.5.1.0 (yes, I know this is old, but I can not update at the moment).

Any ideas or hints? Is there a way to check if it is using the right database? I have to make this work.

Big thanks

**Solution:** It was due to an old PHP version. I switched to 5.4 and it worked right away.

Comment: @Amie Are you able to see the imported products in the Magento admin?

Comment: No, no products are there.

Comment: @Amie can you update your question with first few lines of import csv which you used?

Comment: I solved it, see original post update.